# Multiple styles for one layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have projects with multiple layouts.
I would like to be able to pick different layer styles for different maps, so for example I can have a line appearing in yellow in one layout map and red in another.
I can achieve this by having multiple copies of the layer managed with map themes, this works but starts to get complicated for less familiar users.
I have also looked at storing some of the information in the @map_id as per the expression below where I store the desired colour in the @map_id this also works but isn't very elegant. Any better sugestions?

```
case 
    when  @map_id = 'canvas'
    then '#fff705'
    when array_get(  string_to_array( @map_id ,'-') ,1) is not null
    then array_get(  string_to_array( @map_id ,'-') ,1)
    else '#fff705'
end
```

Comment: How is "better" defined in this context?

Comment: Less complicated for other users would be a start - just wondering if I have missed some functionality to do this properly.  Any alternative options are likely to be interesting .

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem complicated to me once set up properly.

Comment: There are other issues like styling multiple layers and legends looking correct.

Comment: where do you store the expression? Do use an rule based rendering for that?

Comment: @eurojam for my horrendous bodge to work you use that expression to drive variables of the symbology such as line colour or thickness - but storing style variables in the name of an item seems like a poor way to do it. You can create variables for a layout item but these are not accessible for styling layers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using multiple styles per layer has been a feature of QGIS since [version 2.8](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/upcoming-qgis-2-8-multiple-styles-one-layer/) but it doesn't seem to get used or suggested much. You can see a simple example and instructions in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456216/changing-polygon-color-depending-on-visibility-of-background-map-in-qgis/456220#456220).

The example above only shows a simple change from black to white, but because these are layer styles, each style can also control label settings and even attribute forms/constraints etc all in one fell swoop.

However, be aware that unlike map themes, any changes the user makes to any styling will automatically alter the active style - they're not locked in place. Make sure that if they want to mess around, that they first create a separate sandbox style and then muck around, so the existing styles are untouched.

---

You can add, delete and rename styles associated with a layer using

1. Layer Properties (as shown in [official documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#manage-custom-style)),
2. the layer context menu (right-click layer), or
3. using the Layer Styling Panel (press <kbd>F7</kbd> to activate) - multiple paintbrush tabs.

Personally, I find the Layer Styling Panel the easiest way to manage multiple styles.

---

Another example of multiple styles in action as accessed from the Layer Styling Panel to the right:

[image]

---

You can also save multiple styles in one external .qml file via the Style button in Layer Properties, at least as of QGIS 3.28. So by loading this .qml file your user will immediately be able to toggle between different styles for one layer.

Comment: How have I missed/ forgotten this feature?

Comment: Such a modest and smart solution!

Answer (score 3):

I would do it similar but different. Instead of using the condition within a datadefined overriding of the color or other properties, I would use a rule based renderer. the advantage is, that you can use the normal symbol formating tools and you don't have to bother around with color values and so on...

[image]

[image]

Comment: That makes it easier to change a variety of style options, I had a quick look at legends and you can delete the unwanted rule based categories from the legend.